# I need informations about the thread in a NSOperation in concurrency mode

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, concurrency, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have a NSURLConnection asynchrone in NSOperation in concurrency mode.
I know that by default, the NSOperationQueue creates the thread for the NSOperation (non-concurrent). 
But, in concurrency, does it means that i have one thread in another thread ?
if yes, it's a good practice ?

(a example : http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/)

Thx you :)

Answer (score 0):

Dribin's code has some bugs in it which are addressed in a project [exploring concurrent operations](https://github.com/dhoerl/Concurrent_NSOperations) and in a smaller [light-weight concurrent web fetcher](https://github.com/dhoerl/NSOperation-WebFetches-MadeEasy). What is happening here is the operation queue creates and managers one or more threads. The NSURLConnection uses a single thread - it does not create another one. So really there is just one thread consumed in this model.